# ag-grid destroyed warning when routing to another component and then coming back to the grid component

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

How can I get rid-off this warning?

Above is the warning I'm getting in google dev tool console:

ag grid: grid api function setRowData() cannot be called as the grid has been destroyed.
Pleased don't call grid API functions on destroyed grids - as a matter of fact you shouldn't be keeping the API reference, your application has a memory leak! Remove the API reference when the grid is destroyed.

Below is the .ts code:

```
gridApi: any;

@Input()
data: any;
@Input()
gridOptions: any;
@Input()
columnDefs: any;

onGridReady(params: any) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
    params.api.setRowData(data);
    });
}
```

This error happens when I route to another component and then come back to this component.
versions:
ag-agrid: v29
angular: v15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without a working example.

Is `this.data` an Observable?  If you are being warned of a memory leak then please try this:

```
onGridReady(params: any) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.data
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      params.api.setRowData(data);
    });
}
```

Subscribing to observables without using `.pipe(take(<number>))` is a classic source of memory leaks.
Have a read of

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take#why-use-take

or

https://medium.com/@sub.metu/angular-how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-from-subscriptions-8fa925003aa9

Answer (score 1):

The above answer has nothing to do with this issue. The problem is navigating to a page while the subscription is still running will cause the process to still continue even when navigating away from the component. This is easily reproducible in code

```
onGridReady(params: any) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.data
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
     if(params.api.destroyCalled){  <--- Had to check here if destroyed was called while the data is being fetched from the service.
          return;
        }
      params.api.setRowData(data);
    });
}
```

If the destroyed was called before the service returned, then it will still continue to setRowData which will throw the error.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer has nothing to do with this issue. The problem is navigating to a page  ... - this comment is correct.
you need to check !gridApi.destroyCalled

in angular/ts destroyCalled it will not compile as property is private and no accessor provided but it can be bypassed as !this.gridApi['destroyCalled']